# Delete all records when the 50th record is reached - sql/php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I explain my question in detail, I have a table in my db, which incerementates of many records, every time, in my code I have correctly implemented the backup function of deleted data. But I have a problem in my query. I make a trivial example to make people understand.

Example, I have 100 records in my table, the number 1 is the one recorded the longest and the number 100 is the youngest. I want to count 50 records, and delete from 51 to 100, so that the 50 oldest records are deleted and backed up, and the 50 younger ones remain, creating a continuous cycle of deletion and backup.

Stupid example that cannot occur but is only to make people understand:
if I have 30 records, do not delete anything until I have at least 50, 50 or more, delete 50

I'm 30, don't delete anything up to 50

I have 51, delete1, the oldest and I have 50 again.

I have 60, delete 10 from the oldest and I have 50 again.

My code that I put below for those who want to do tests, create a folder and a backup file and correctly record every deletion field, but it doesn't do what I wrote that I need, but every time the script is launched, eventually erases all records in the db

```
<?php

    //Start the session
    session_start();

    //Include connection
    include 'connessione.php';

    //Query to get stuff from database
    $query_string = "SELECT * FROM utenti ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1  ";
    $query = mysqli_query($connessione, $query_string);

    //Get results
    $results = mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    //Make that into a JSON array
    $results = json_encode( $results );



    function makeDirectory($path, $mode) 
      {
        $return = mkdir($path, $mode, true);
        return $return === true || is_dir($path);
      }
        $path = 'backup_LOG';
        $mode = 0777;
        $risultato = makeDirectory($path, $mode);


    //Put those results in a file (create if file not exist)
    $fileName = 'backup_LOG/backup_file_' . time() . '.txt';
    $file = fopen( $fileName , 'a'  );
    fwrite( $file, $results );
    fclose( $file );


//Delete the rows that you just backed up, but only if there are 50 or more.
if( sizeof( $results ) >= 1 )
{
    $query_delete = "DELETE FROM utenti ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    mysqli_query( $connessione, $query_delete );
}
?>
```

**FINAL CODE**

```
<?php

    //Start the session
    session_start();

    //Include connection
    include 'connessione.php';

 $query = $connessione->query("
    SELECT *
    FROM utenti 
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 9999999999999999 -- just a very high number
    OFFSET 1
");

$results = $query->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $results = json_encode( $results );

if (count($results) > 0) {
    // @todo backup the data 

    function makeDirectory($path, $mode) 
      {
        $return = mkdir($path, $mode, true);
        return $return === true || is_dir($path);
      }
        $path = 'backup_LOG';
        $mode = 0777;
        $risultato = makeDirectory($path, $mode);


$results = json_encode( $results );

//Put those results in a file (create if file not exist)
$fileName = 'backup_file_' . time() . '.txt';
$file = fopen( $fileName , 'a'  );
fwrite( $file, $results );
fclose( $file );


    // delete fetched rows
    $firstId = reset($results)['id'];
    $lastId  = end($results)['id'];
    $stmt = $connessione->prepare("DELETE FROM utenti WHERE id BETWEEN ? and ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $firstId, $lastId);
    $stmt->execute();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `OFFSET 50` to skip 50 "jungest" rows. Then use first and last `id` from the fetched data to delete the rows between them.

```
$query = $connessione->query("
    SELECT *
    FROM utenti 
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 9999999999999999 -- just a very high number
    OFFSET 50
");

$results = $query->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if (count($results) > 0) {
    // @todo backup the data 

    // delete fetched rows
    $firstId = reset($results)['id'];
    $lastId  = end($results)['id'];
    $stmt = $connessione->prepare("DELETE FROM utenti WHERE id BETWEEN ? and ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $firstId, $lastId);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Note: `LIMIT 9999999999999999` is a workaround. We don't want a LIMIT. But in MySQL it's not possible to use `OFFSET` without `LIMIT`. If you don't taht "magic" number, you can also use the following query instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM utenti 
WHERE id <= (
  SELECT id
  FROM utenti 
  ORDER BY id DESC
  LIMIT 1
  OFFSET 50
)
```

Comment: I had also thought of a static value, but calculating that, in the span of 5 days, I recorded 20,000 records, and it is still not open to the public, I wouldn't want my brain to have to deal with something unattractive in a while, here because I was looking for a dynamic solution

Comment: @user11317164 What is your point? I don't get it. What do you mean by "static value"?

Comment: what happens when you reach: 9999999999999999?

Comment: You never reach `9999999999999999`, because it's a 20 digits number which is greater than any number of rows in a table with `AUTO_INCREMENT` primary key. It is a workaround, because you can't use `OFFSET` without `LIMIT`. This is how you get all rows except of first N rows in MySQL.

Comment: i m not make build your code with mine, can u write a complete answer please

Comment: I'm showing you, how to select the rows and delete them. I'm not going to write everything for you. That's against my religion ;-) - You just need `session_start(); include 'connessione.php';` and your backup code where i wrote `// @todo backup the data`.

Comment: I am very pleased to see how the words humility and helping others come back to you, but obviously it will be your religion's fault to write broken codes, along with meaningless faces ..... ;-)

Comment: If anything doesn't work for you, then you should be more specific. "your code broke all" doesn't help.

Comment: if I simply leave the session and the connection, not putting any instruction inside the if loop, but I limit myself only to copy your query and your if loop, missing instructions, I get error 500, it breaks, that's why I asked you kindly if you could give me a hand

Comment: There was a missing semicolon here `$stmt->bind_param('ii', $firstId, $lastId)`. You should learn to debug the code.

Comment: you see that when you want your religion works miracles, I know that you were a child with an imaginary friend as a child, you smile at life and beautiful, and thanks for your help and your contribution

Comment: Note: **debugging** is the most important skill in programming. Good luck!

Comment: Paul if implemented the backup code into if cycle, i have a problem, because nothing delete into db and obviously nothing backup, why?

Comment: Because you are overwriting `$results = json_encode( $results );`. Use different variable names.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8, you could use window functions in a subquery to rank and count the records, and then join it with the main table:

```
DELETE u
FROM utenti u
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) rn,
        COUNT(*) OVER() cnt
    FROM utenti
) x ON u.id = x.id
WHERE x.cnt - 50 - x.rn >= 0
```

NB : as most operations that modify data, you want to run this inside a *database transaction*.

Comment: This could work. But what if the backup fails and the DB has already deleted the records? EDIT: Nevermind, I thought you were combining the queries. In this case, what if new records come in between the select and delete?

Comment: @drakin8564: as most operations that modify data, you want to run this inside a database transaction.

Comment: I completely agree. However, he is not. Might want to mention that in your answer. The OP user may not have experience with transactions.

Comment: @drakin8564: yes it as worth mentioning this, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to replace your first query with something like this:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM utenti 
   WHERE id < (SELECT MIN(id) FROM (SELECT id FROM utenti ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50))
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

In your php, between calling mysqli_fetch_all() and json_encode(), add this line:

```
$maxDeleteID = $results[count($results)-1]['id'];
```

Change your delete query to use this new php variable:

```
"DELETE FROM utenti WHERE id <= ". $maxDeleteID;
```

This should pull all records prior to the newest 50, and then make sure that nothing that is not in that backup is deleted. Records could be added to the table between your select and delete so you need to save that max id from your select and use it to make sure you dont delete anything that wasn't backed up.

Comment: does not delete anything and obviously the backup returns me null

Comment: If there were not over 50 records in the table it wouldn't delete anything... what is the result of that select query?